# javascript toLocaleString returns 0

Tags: javascript

I find toLocaleString function very odd.

the following line will return `0.003`:

```
alert(0.0031.toLocaleString(2))
```

this line will return `0`:

```
alert(0.00031.toLocaleString(2))
```

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toLocaleString() method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of this number.

numObj.toLocaleString([locales [, options]]) has two parameters.

Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

```js
    var num = 0.00031;
    console.log(num.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}));
    console.log(num.toLocaleString(undefined, { maximumFractionDigits: 4}));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid parameters to the method toLocaleString.

You can use minimumFractionDigits param like this:

```js
var res = 0.00031.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 4});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

`2` is not a valid argument for `toLocaleString` method of a `Number`. You may only pass a locale, which is a string, and and an object of options.

Options object can be used, among other things, to specify number of fraction digits:

```
number.toLocaleString(undefined, { maximumFractionDigits: 4 })
```

And the default value for it happens to be 3:

> **maximumFractionDigits**
>
> The maximum number of fraction digits to use.
>   Possible values are from 0 to 20; the default for plain number
>   formatting is the larger of minimumFractionDigits and 3; the default
>   for currency formatting is the larger of minimumFractionDigits and the
>   number of minor unit digits provided by the ISO 4217 currency code
>   list (2 if the list doesn't provide that information); the default for
>   percent formatting is the larger of minimumFractionDigits and 0.

Answer (score 0):

toLocaleString truncates and rounds the decimal number to 3 digits after the decimal.

```
0.0005.toLocaleString()
```

for example will return 0.001.
The 2 in that you pass in as a method param doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The number 2 in the argument is not making any difference. [**toLocaleString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the number.

In the second case of your problem it is basically `0.000` which is equal to 0

```js
console.log("Passing argument    " + 0.0031.toLocaleString(2))

console.log("Without argument    " + 0.0031.toLocaleString())

console.log("Zeros  " + 0.000)
```

Answer (score 0):

number.toLocaleString() returns language sensitive representation of the number. Here in your case you are first not passing any locale information, and you are not telling this function that what is your max fraction limit.

See this example

```
0.0003.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2})
"0.00"
0.0003.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 3})
"0.000"
0.0003.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 4})
"0.0003
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-13.2.1), first two arguments to toLocaleString is `locale` and `options`

> When the toLocaleString method is called with optional arguments
> locales and options, the following steps are taken:

When this API receive value 2 or 3, it first try to [resolve locales](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-9.2.5) and if not found the check within the [supported locales](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-9.2.8).

The resolved locale is used as an effective locale to [format the number](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#FormatNumber) as per the locale as per [Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/).

> NOTE It is recommended that implementations use the locale data
> provided by the Common Locale Data Repository (available at
> http://cldr.unicode.org/).

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#locales_argument)

> The locales argument must be either a string holding a BCP 47 language
> tag, or an array of such language tags. If the locales argument is not
> provided or is undefined, the runtime's default locale is used.
>
> A BCP 47 language tag defines a language and minimally contains a
> primary language code. In its most common form it can contain, in
> order: a language code, a script code, and a country or region code,
> all separated by hyphens. While the tag is not case sensitive, it is
> recommended to use title case for script code, upper case for country
> and region codes and lower case for everything else.

**Finally**, lookup is performed to find the best fit from the supported locales as per [BCP47 logic](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647#section-3.4) as per locales registered in [IANA language subtag registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry) as per various attributes of a language mentioned.

`2` doesn't matches any of the supported locales so, default **maximum fraction digits** as per your system environment is used from [available value](https://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/lists/list_one.xml) (appears to be 3 in your case.)

Hence you get

```
0.00031.toLocaleString(2) //"0"

0.0031.toLocaleString(2) //"0.003"
```